# How to add more columns to pivot table in many to many relations in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, many-to-many

I have 2 models united by a Many to Many relationship, in this case is Policies and Coverages so far it works fine, but I want to add another column to the pivot table since it wont work on any of the modeled tables (I want to add a IntegerField with the name 'amount' so I can store how much money are we covering for that specific coverage in that specific Insurance Police)

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    """Insurance Policies Model"""

    number = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.OneToOneField(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    comission = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    salesperson = models.ForeignKey(Salesperson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    rif = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'policies'
```

```
class Coverage(models.Model):
    """Coverage of the different types of policies"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    policies = models.ManyToManyField(Policy)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'coverages'
```

I made the migrations and the pivot table was made without problems, but I don't know how to add another field to the pivot table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a [**`through=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for that. In fact if you do not specify this yourself, Django will automatically make an "implicit model". For example:

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    # ...

class Coverage(models.Model):
    # ...
    policies = models.ManyToManyField(Policy, through='CoveragePolicy')

class CoveragePolicy(models.Model):
    policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coverage = models.ForeignKey(Coverage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

So now you can create a relation object between a policy `p1` and a coverage `c2` with:

```
CoveragePolicy.objects.create(policy=p1, coverage=c2, amount=1)
```

You can obtain the related set of `CoveragePolicy` objects for a policy `p1` with:

```
p1.coveragepolicy_set.all()
```

and then inspect the `amount` and the related `coverage` it has.

Django however will have troubles migrating from an existing through model to another one, so you probably will have to remove the migration file, and create a fresh one with the new model instead (and undo the changes in the database of the old one).