# How to add custom field in manytomany through table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have a model which has manytomany relation with another model. This creates a hidden through table with two foreign key field of previous two tables. Now I want to add custom field in addition to the existing two foreign key field in the through table.

**Model One:**

```py
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=264)
```

**Model Two:**

```py
class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    many_field = models.ManyToManyField(ModelOne, related_name='some_name')
    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=264)
```

**Auto created hidden through table:**

```py
class appname_modeltwo_modelone(models.Model):
    model_one_id= models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
    model_two_id= models.ForeignKey(ModelTwo)
    custom_field= models.CharField(max_length=264) # New Custom Field I want to add
```

How can I add new custom field here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add more columns to pivot table in many to many relations in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527740/how-to-add-more-columns-to-pivot-table-in-many-to-many-relations-in-django)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can add extra fields on many-to-many relationships using the through argument to point to the model that will act as an intermediary** according to [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

*In your example*

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=264)

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    many_field = models.ManyToManyField(ModelOne, related_name='some_name', through='IntermediateModel')
    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=264)

class IntermediateModel(models.Model):
    model_one = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_two = models.ForeignKey(ModelTwo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    custom_field = models.DateField()
    custom_field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```