# ERD to django models ? Many to many relatioship with attribut

Tags: sql, django, entity-relationship, create-table

How should I translate this Entity Relationship Diagram to Django models ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add custom field in manytomany through table in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687277/how-to-add-custom-field-in-manytomany-through-table-in-django)

Comment: Yes it answer
But, to insert new record of Employee i want that give me to select project and if i select one then i can insert number of hours
(How to add this to the Admin page ?)